# Android application distribution

Tags: android, distribution

could you explain me steps for android app distribution.
I can sign it and publish to Android market. But can I offer clients to load this application without market? e.g from company web site? if yes, can I still use self-signed certificate?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you can still use your self-signed certificate and have them install it from outside of the market. the user needs to have the setting Application->Unknown Sources checked to allow them to install though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can put it on the market, and also link to it from you website. But to install from your website the clients will have to have checked "install non-market applications" in their Android Settings.

Comment: So, when I offer app from my web site - can it be signed with self-signed certificate?

Comment: Oh, if it exact apk that is uploaded to market - does it means that it cost nothing to publish app to market? no certificate, etc?

Comment: You have to have a google checkout account for the Market which I think costs $25 one-time-fee. But if you export the apk from Eclipse you can put it on the market as well as your website.